# perl extract string and scientific number

Tags: perl

I have data in particular format.

capacitor #(.c(**3.58782e-14**)) **c_1310** (**vsub**, **vss_res**);

I want to extract those highlighted in BOLD from the data set. I tried using regex

```
$cap = $line =~ /([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-]?[0-9]+)?)/ ;
($net1, $net2) = $line =~ /\(([A-Za-z0-9_]*) \, ([A-Za-z0-9_]*)\)/ ;
```

$line contains each data line. Need help in getting the regex corrected.

I have a solution using split() function but regex would be better I think.

Comment: Your regex is almost there: (1) To only group the pattern forming the exponent (so to be able to use `?` on it) use the non-capturing `(?: ... )`. (The way it is, with `()`, it captures the exponent separately) (2) Please show a sample input string -- but if after the number you need the rest as it seems just add `(.*)` at the end of the pattern (3) Then you need to assign those matches, strictly in list context, so `my ($v1, $v2,...) = $line =~ /.../`

Comment: What's the problem with your current code? What do you expect to get, and what are you actually getting?

Comment: @matt -- I get value " 1" for the $cap variable. "Use of uninitialized value $net1 in print" for the $net1 variable when I try to print.

Comment: @zdim. more reading on the regex helped me understand what you are saying. Thanks for the reply

Comment: In scalar context, the match operator returns a true value if the match is successful (`1`). In list context, it returns the captured substrings. It sounds like you need to impose list context.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please remember in the future to (also) make the question complete -- with sample input and expected output, and a clear statement on what is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the format of data is always the same, something like this should work

```
my $line = 'capacitor #(.c(3.58782e-14)) c_1310 (vsub, vss_res);';
my ($net1, $net2, $net3) = $line =~ /\(.+\((.+)\)\)\s+(.+)\s+\((.+)\)/;
```

Answer (score 0):

The original post seemed to do some checking and validation (in contrast with matching '.' which matches anything) and I will suggest a more validating version here:

```
use Modern::Perl;

use Regexp::Common;

my $line = 'capacitor #(.c(3.58782e-14)) c_1310 (vsub, vss_res);';
my ($cap, $cap_no, $net1, $net2) = $line =~ /
    \([^(]+\( ($RE{num}{real}) \)\)
    \s+(\w+)\s+
    \(
        (\w*) ,\s*
        (\w*)
    \)
/x;

say "cap: $cap cap_no: $cap_no net1: $net1 net2: $net2";
```

OUTPUT:

```
cap: 3.58782e-14 cap_no: c_1310 net1: vsub net2: vss_res
```